# Django 1.8 unable to match url patterns using multiple url conf files

Tags: python, django

I'm running through a basic project using Django 1.8 and I'm not sure if I am missing something in the documentation or have just misunderstood it.

I am having a problem with `urls.py` recognizing the correct url patterns. 
I am using [This section of the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) for examples.

My project directory structure is:

```
integrations 
  |--integrations
           |--- migrations
                    |-- ....
           |-- __init__.py
           |-- admin.py
           |-- models.py
           |-- settings.py
           |-- urls.py
           |-- views.py
           |-- wsgi.py
  |-- templates
           |-- ....
  |-- manage.py
```

Specifically, contents of `urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wsa/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<customer_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.address_detail, name='address_detail'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

As you can see, I have `wsa` listed as a url pattern in this file. Based upon the documentation referred to above, this should be eliminated and instead be `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`

The documentation also shows a different directory structure with, what appears to be a root `urls.py` in the root directory alongside `manage.py`. This is where the documentation indicates I would put my `wsa` pattern and include in the child `urls.py`; however when I do so, that file is not read and instead my url patterns begin to fail:

```
Using the URLconf defined in integrations.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='index']
The current URL, wsa/, didn't match any of these.
```

Corrosponding url.py files that cause failure:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin   

urlpatterns = [      
    url(r'^wsa/', include('integrations.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

integrations\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'views.index', name='index'),      
]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood a few things here.

The "integrations" subdirectory is not supposed to contain model or view code. It is where your settings and wsgi files go, and also the main urls.py. That is the file referred to in the documentation.

Your actual code should go into a new app, let's say "wsa", created with `./manage.py startapp wsa`. That's where you put the models, admin, and views files, and *also* the subsidiary urls.py. So your main urls would now contain `include('wsa.urls')`.

Comment: I figured I had missed something - Thanks